# Converting base 16 value to base 62 using Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I want to convert base 16 value to base 62 value and this value to be used in jmeter script execution.

- UID_Hex = C8ED6D6046D34807BC5F0EBF065072EC
- TO Converted Value = 678y8VC5aSunoh06J8BhOe

I have a scenario where I have to fetch UID_Hex from DB and convert it into base 62 value and use it in further script execution.

How to convert base 16 to base 62 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Example code:

```
static def base16ToBase10(String base16) {
    def result = new BigInteger('0')
    def chars = "0123456789ABCDEF"

    base16.each { c ->
        result = result * 16 + chars.indexOf(c.toUpperCase())
    }

    result
}

static def base10ToBase62(BigInteger base10) {
    def chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    def result = ''

    while (base10 > 0) {
        def remainder = base10.mod(62)
        result = chars[remainder.intValue()] + result
        base10 = base10.divide(62 as BigInteger)
    }

    result
}

def UID_Hex = 'C8ED6D6046D34807BC5F0EBF065072EC'


def TO_Converted_Value = base10ToBase62(base16ToBase10(UID_Hex))

//do what you need with the converted value here
```

Demo:

[image]